# case_when doesn't work with multiple conditions over multiple variables

Tags: r

I just discovered that, case_when might not work if a variable is recoded based on multiple variables.

Reproducible data:

```
data <- data.frame(f103 = c(2, NA, NA, 1, 2, 2),
                       f76 = c(2, NA, NA, NA, 3, 3),
                       f4 = c(1,3,3,1,1,2))
```

The following code produces the same results for var1 and var 2 (which is not what I want):

```
reprdata <- reprdata %>%
  mutate(var1 = f4) %>% 
  mutate(var1 = case_when(f103 == 2 ~ 3, TRUE ~ as.numeric(var1))) %>%
  mutate(var2 = f4) %>% 
  mutate(var2 = case_when(f103 == 2 ~ 3, f76 == 1 ~ 1, f76 == 2 ~ 2, f76 == 3 ~ 3, TRUE ~ as.numeric(var2)))
```

The following produces the correct result (i.e., the solution to my problem):

```
reprdata <- reprdata %>%
  mutate(var1 = f4) %>% 
  mutate(var1 = case_when(f103 == 2 ~ 3, TRUE ~ as.numeric(var1))) %>%
  mutate(var2 = f4) %>% 
  mutate(var2 = case_when(f103 == 2 ~ 3, TRUE ~ as.numeric(var2))) %>%
  mutate(var2 = case_when(f76 == 1 ~ 1, f76 == 2 ~ 2, f76 == 3 ~ 3, TRUE ~ as.numeric(var2)))
```

(I am aware that in this snippet of my data, the f103 condition for var1 is superfluous, still, I wouldn't expect it to cause this issue.)

I'd be interested to know if someone can explain to my **why this problem occurs** and how to **prevent** it in future.

Comment: I don't understand what the logic is that you are trying to code. Can you describe the desired output in words? `case_when` will stop at the first matching case. If you need to combine data from different columns, you'll need to include `&` (and) and `|` (or) statements into your conditions.

Comment: I share the confusion of @MrFlick. But maybe it helps to clarify that `case_when` tests its conditions *in order of appearance* and stops at the first one that's true. It has essentially the exact same behaviour as a long chain of `if (…) … else if (…) …`s: the relevant missing part of the puzzle in your understanding seems to be the **`else`** part.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I indeed had not thought of this. This is also more understandable to me than the "bottom up" explanation from @harre, which you've questioned. Thanks for taking the time to explain

Comment: Okay, let me transfer my comment into an answer for better findability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `case_when` expression is essentially a (vectorised) form of `if … else if …`. Its arguments are evaluated until the first match is found, *and then it stops*.

In other words, this sub-expression

```
case_when(f103 == 2 ~ 3, f76 == 1 ~ 1, f76 == 2 ~ 2, f76 == 3 ~ 3, TRUE ~ as.numeric(var2))
```

is equivalent to (again, a vectorised form of)

```
if (f103 == 2) 3
  else if (f76 == 1) 1
  else if (f76 == 2) 2
  else if (f76 == 3) 3
  else as.numeric(var2)
```

To vectorise it, you could rewrite this expression using `ifelse` (or `if_else` from ‘dplyr’) but this would be excessively verbose, and I have no clue how to format it in a compact yet readable way (the following looks *ok*, but the auto-formatter will expand the flat structure rightwards, leading to extremely indented code):

```
ifelse(f103 == 2, 3,
  ifelse(f76 == 1, 1,
  ifelse(f76 == 2, 2,
  ifelse(f76 == 3, 3,
  as.numeric(var2)))))
```

And hence ‘dplyr’ gives us `case_when` to express this more readably. But the logic is exactly the same.

So, if you want to prioritise the value of `f76` over the value of `f103`, you need to invert your conditions:

```
case_when(
  f76 == 1 ~ 1,
  f76 == 2 ~ 2,
  f76 == 3 ~ 3,
  f103 == 2 ~ 3,
  TRUE ~ as.numeric(var2)
)
```

… and of course this can be shortened as shown in the other answer by merging all three cases that test the value of `f76`.